# The black and white photos in the Proof Copy of my book are washed out and without blacks

Tags: color, adobe-indesign, color-profile, color-spaces

The black and white photos in the Proof Copy of my book (non-coated paper) are washed out and have no deep blacks, or hardly any blacks. Working from InDesign to a PDF file, how do I ensure that my B&W photos are printed with blacks on a digital printer, in this case CreateSpace POD?

Answer (score 1):

Try converting your images to CMYK so you can control the colors. You can take down the undercoat and boost black for deep-shadowed areas. In Photoshop, the setting that works well for my printers is: U.S. Sheet Fit Coated v2.

Other suggestion is supporting Black in large areas by adding grey behind it to preserve the color. C=60, M=40, Y=40, K=100.

In InDesign you can check the Overprint preview under View > Overprint Preview. You can also spot problems (washed out areas, fading, etc.) in Window > Output > Separations Preview.

Finally, you can talk with your printer about their specific suggestions for their digital printers and preparing the files for richer blacks.